# need regular expression to return second last directory form path

Tags: regex

I'm trying to have a regular expression return the second last directory from a file path.

I have a file path that looks like something like this:

```
C:\first\second\third\fourth\fifth\filename.txt
```

I want a regular expression to return everything up to the second-to-last directory (including the second-to-last directory); in this case everything up to and including the fourth directory:

```
C:\first\second\third\fourth\
```

The regular expression I currently have is:

```
[^\\]+\\?$
```

but this returns up to the last directory as so:

```
C:\first\second\third\fourth\fifth\
```

Thanks.

Comment: What programming language (or regex flavor) are you using? If Lookaheads are supported, you may use `^.+(?=(?:\\[^\\]+){2}$)`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3uZ2DZ/1).

Comment: What language??

Comment: @41686d6564 I think you wanted `[^\\]+(?=(?:\\[^\\]+){2}$)` since OP just wants the second-to-last directory and not everything leading up to it.

Comment: Apologize for the confusion.  I did want everything leading up to the second to last directory with the second to last directory included.  such as: C:\first\second\third\fourth\

Comment: @MonkeyZeus According to the expected output they gave (after "as such"), it looks like they do need to capture everything up to and including "fourth". OP even said _"I want a regular expression to return the **up to** the second last directory"_. I still could be wrong though because there are parts of the question that don't make sense.

Comment: I just edited the question hopefully its a little bit more clear.

Comment: @41686d6564 You're right, I should have paid more attention to the examples. The wording was a bit confusing.

Comment: @41686d6564 Looks like we're both wrong. The trailing slash is expected per the example so `^.+\\(?=[^\\]+\\[^\\]+$)` would be needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can repeat parts of "paths" and capture those in group 1. After that, match the second last path name, backslash and the last path name till the end of the string.

```
^((?:[^\\]+\\)+)[^\\]+\\[^\\]+$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:[^\\]+\\)+` Repeat 1+ times matching any char except `\`, then match `\`
- `)` Close group 1
- `[^\\]+\\[^\\]+` Match 1+ times any char except `\`, match `\`, match any char except `\`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/W7ECEW/1)

You might also extend your pattern to match any char except a `\` and then  a `\` before it to match the part that you want to remove. But that does not guarantee that there is at least a part with a backslash before it.

```
[^\\]+\\[^\\]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BeTeyr/1)

Comment: This expression works out as I want.  Can you please explain the regular expression please.  I understand in [^\\]+\\[^\\]+$  the [^\\]+ matches all characters up to backslash.

Comment: @SSS I have added a breakdown of the separate parts for the first pattern.